# Playing RTSP audio on iPhone using Wunderadio code

Tags: iphone, audio, rtsp

I need to play an RTSP audio stream in an iPhone app, so I've been trying to run the the Wunderradio code (http://wunderradio.com/code.html) but I get some errors (copied below)..

Usually errors like these mean that Frameworks are not installed, but in this case they all seem present and correct.

Has anyone got the Wunderadio code to run? I'm stuck!

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MusicViewController", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-MusicViewController in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_URLBackgroundOperation", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-URLBackgroundOperation in SkinViewController.o


  "_Status_GetCurrentStatus", referenced from:


  -[LevelMeterView updateBargraph:] in LevelMeterView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FavoriteViewController", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-FavoriteViewController in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


  "_Status_SetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:


  -[WunderRadioAppDelegate applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:] in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


  "_CMAudioPlayerAudioDidStopNotification", referenced from:


  _CMAudioPlayerAudioDidStopNotification$non_lazy_ptr in DebugController.o


 (maybe you meant: _CMAudioPlayerAudioDidStopNotification$non_lazy_ptr)


  "_CMAudioPlayerAudioIsAvailableNotification", referenced from:


  _CMAudioPlayerAudioIsAvailableNotification$non_lazy_ptr in DebugController.o


 (maybe you meant: _CMAudioPlayerAudioIsAvailableNotification$non_lazy_ptr)


  "_Status_SetNewStatusString", referenced from:


  -[SkinViewController setShowingPlay:] in SkinViewController.o


   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RadioTimeBrowser", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-RadioTimeBrowser in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


   "_gStreamingAudioPlayerTimerMax", referenced from:


  _gStreamingAudioPlayerTimerMax$non_lazy_ptr in PreferenceViewController.o


 (maybe you meant: _gStreamingAudioPlayerTimerMax$non_lazy_ptr)


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebViewController", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-WebViewController in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


  "_CMAudioPlayerAudioIsDoneNotification", referenced from:


  _CMAudioPlayerAudioIsDoneNotification$non_lazy_ptr in DebugController.o


 (maybe you meant: _CMAudioPlayerAudioIsDoneNotification$non_lazy_ptr)


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EnhancedAlertView", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-EnhancedAlertView in DebugController.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WXRadioItem", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-WXRadioItem in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SettingsAndKeyChainStorage", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-SettingsAndKeyChainStorage in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-Reachability in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBSettingsManager", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-WBSettingsManager in WunderRadioAppDelegate.o


  "_CMAudioPlayerAudioDidPlayNotification", referenced from:


  _CMAudioPlayerAudioDidPlayNotification$non_lazy_ptr in SkinViewController.o


 (maybe you meant: _CMAudioPlayerAudioDidPlayNotification$non_lazy_ptr)


  "_ExpandString", referenced from:


  -[DebugController runPressed:] in DebugController.o


  -[DebugController lngPressed:] in DebugController.o


  -[SkinViewController expandString:] in SkinViewController.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebAudioPlayer", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref-to-WebAudioPlayer in SkinViewController.o


   ld: symbol(s) not found


    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Has anyone else got the Wunderadio code to run ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can only build device target now. the symbol in Common/build/release-iphonesimulator/libcommon.a seems have different naming mangling than your current complier.
eg, ".objc_class_name_MusicViewController" used but "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MusicViewController" excepted.
I scope into libcommon.a and show it built with iphone os sdk 3.1 with gcc 4.2.1 5577 (x86), maybe they only test on device and forgot to sync simulator lib?

Answer (score 0):

add the files in the Command or RadioShared floder to the project.